# Android - java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

IDE: Android Studio

I have the static library located under the "jniLibs" folder.

[image]

I also loaded that library. Here is the code I used:

```
static 
{
    System.loadLibrary("elianjni");
}
```

The native methods were declared on a separate class(ElianNative) as:

```
public native int InitSmartConnection(String paramString, int paramInt1, int paramInt2);    

public native int StartSmartConnection(String paramString1, String paramString2, String paramString3, byte paramByte);
```

However when I called the method `InitSmartConnection` the app crashed and the error was:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.monitor.camera.connect.ElianNative.InitSmartConnection:(Ljava/lang/String;II)I

at com.monitor.camera.connect.ElianNative.InitSmartConnection(Native Method)
```

I don't know the possible cause of this because I just copied this library from another **WORKING** project and then did the same thing on declaring the methods and importing the necessary headers.

What can be the possible cause of such problem? I searched on stack, some say that it's the absence of Java keyword before the method in the .c file. However I don't think that this can be the problem because like what I said, this is used in another project which is working fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have copied native library binary files (`.so`) from other project you must ensure that:

- declarations of native methods in java are still the same, i.e. both method name and signature remain unchanged
- declarations of native methods are placed in the class with the same name and package as in donor project.

Also check that `System.loadLibrary()` ends successfully, without error logs in logcat.